# I want my program to access webpages, my emails, Facebook and twitter without opening windows for them

Tags: error-handling, speech-recognition

I have been trying to make a V.I(virtual intelligence) that can respond to your questions and you can tell it to do some things like tell me how many emails I have, tell me if someone just sent me an email, and if I ask it questions it can search a webpage e.g if I ask it what is reading, it can search Wikipedia and tell me the first few words after the word reading. And this is the code so far, for the speech recognition and replies to certain questions. Please can some tell me how to correct some of the errors like the one where the V.I says hello, the IDE says unreachable code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq ;
using System.Web ;


namespace JAPA
{ 
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine _myrecognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine ();
        SpeechSynthesizer EDI = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        //The string Cevent(Conputer event) is a variable that will be used for the termination of the computer.
        string Cevent;
        //The string QandA(Question and answer) this is a mehtod full of cases for a respond from japa
        string QandA;
        //this is a string to be used  for Japa when he  is communicating
        string Japaspeech;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ///This block of code handles the SpeechRecognition
            _myrecognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            _myrecognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler < SpeechRecognizedEventArgs > (_myrecognizer_SpeechRecognized);
            _myrecognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }



        private void _myrecognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



        /// <summary>
        /// This block contains code for the termination of the computer.
        /// </summary>
        public void computerdeath()
        {
            switch (Cevent)
            {
              case " shutdown":
                  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown,'-s'");
                  break;
              case " closeup ":
                  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown,'-s'");
                  break;
              case "log off ":
                  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown,'-l'");
                  break;
              case "hibernate":
                  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown,'-h'");
                  break;
              case "restart":
                  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown,'-r'");
                  break;
            }
        }



        //This methid contains cases for incasity of questions by user.
        public void Myname()
        {  
            switch ( QandA)
            {
                case "your name ":
                break;

                case "identity":
                break;

                case " your alias":
                break;

                case   "your surname":
                break;
            }
        }

        void _myrecognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender,SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (Japaspeech)
            {  //This part heads the greetings japa will recieve and her reply
                case "Hi":
                    break;
                case "Hey there":
                    break;
                case "Mate":
                    break;
                case "doing*":
                    break;

                case "going on*":
                    break ;
                    //This part of the code replies the greetings  
                    EDI.Speak("Hello there");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is unreachable code at the line:

```
EDI.Speak("Hello there");
```

This code is unreachable because you have a break statement directly before it. I would advise learning about how switch statements work before you continue, because it looks like all of the breaks in `switch (Japaspeech)` are wrong. Try imitating how the code will run by hand to see where things will go wrong.

Comment: I don't understand how they are wrong I stayed all night reading switches and breaks ' please can you enlighten me

Comment: The last one is wrong because you have the `break` before the statement, so the switch will end before the statement gets executed. I am assuming that you wanted the `EDI.Speak("Hello there");` to execute regardless of which case the `Japaspeech` matched, which would make all of the other breaks unnecessary, as they all end the switch whenever a match is found, and if you left them out then the `EDI.Speak("Hello there");` would execute on any match. That assumption could be completely wrong though, I don't know exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you!, what am trying to do is make EDI responds to any of the cases , depending on which one is said by the user. Thank You for helping me I appreciate it.

Comment: please who can answer the first question about accessing emails and  stuff

Comment: The question here was about fixing logic errors in the code, not about implementing the extensions. You should mark the answer as accepted, or indicate why it doesn't answer the question as it is, and then you should really ask about the email as a separate question, where you show what you have tried so far.